# How to simplify a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

A matrix

```
    A=SparseArray[{{1,1}->1/2 a Conjugate[a]+1/2 b Conjugate[b],{2,2}->1/2 a Conjugate[a]+1/2 b Conjugate[b]}]
```

a and b are possibilities, and I want to simplify the matrix A.

```
    FullSimplify[A, {1 >= a >= 0, 1 >= b >= 0}] // MatrixForm
```

This give me
[image]

There still "Conjugate" in the matrix.

Comment: `Simplify[Normal[A],Element[a|b,Reals]]` or `Simplify[Normal[A],0<=a<=1&&0<=b<=1]` Somehow the `SparseArray` seems to be resisting the `Simplify` and `Normal` turns it back into an "ordinary" matrix.

Comment: wow! it works!!

Comment: Or `ComplexExpand[A // Normal] // MatrixForm`